# POSIX glob -- how to match one-or-more [:digit:]

Tags: linux, posix, sh, glob

I want to iterate over `foo.log` and its log rotated siblings `foo.1.gz` and `foo.2.gz` from newest to oldest, with code that isn't fooled by the presence of `foo.bar`

Happily, `logrotate` names things such that newest-to-oldest and alphabetical are the same ordering.

My original attempt was `for f in $(ls -t foo.*); do ...` but `shellcheck` said `Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs. [SC2045]`. Plus this code matches `foo.bar` which is not desired.

But **how do you match an arbitrary number of digits with a glob pattern?** (Or is this not supported?) I only know how to list each number of digits explicitly. For example, the following handles 1 and 2 digit numbers and correctly excludes `foo.1bar.gz` but doesn't handle `foo.123.gz` (and I'm not doing the right thing to cause `glob`ing to take place!)

`for f in foo.log foo.[[:digit:]].gz foo.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]].gz; do ...`

I could assume that no one keeps over 100 log rotated siblings, but I'd prefer not to.

Looking for a POSIX compliant solution...

Edit: the logrotate conf compresses for some files and doesn't compress for others. So not all siblings end in `.gz`.

Comment: I had the exact same situation, and my solution was to do the opposite; use a regular glob `file.log*` to gather all log files, then in a `for` loop check each one  with `if [[ $LOG == *.gz ]]; then` for differential handling for `.gz` files and non-gz files. Not as elegant but easier to deal with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A glob pattern is not a regular expression.  See glob(7) for the syntax.

There is no glob pattern to match a series of digits.  You can get close with `foo.[0-9]*.gz`.  If that picks up some names you don't want, you can filter them out with a regex, maybe something like:

```
echo foo.[0-9]*.* | tr ' ' \\n | grep -E '[.][0-9]+([.]gz)?$'
```

You can probably use a glob pattern and rely on the shell for ordering, given the constraints you presented.  You can check if your shell renders filenames for a glob pattern in sorted order with **sort**:

```
echo foo.[0-9]*.gz | tr \  \\n | sort -c
```

But it's also OK to parse the output of `ls -t` unless you're being *extremely* rigorous.  The guidance from `shellcheck` is good advice: many people seem to want to parse `ls` output when a simple glob would do, and to depend on `ls` to behave the same way across different systems is to invite error.  That said, you're only asking for `ls` to sort the filenames by time, producing a single column of output.  Anything else you might do would be more error-prone.

Comment: Ah but `foo.*.gz` matches `foo.bar.log.1.gz`, the first log rotated sibling of `foo.bar.log` which is "unrelated" to `foo.log`, which is why I'm trying to use `[[:digit:]]` ...

Comment: It's closer. But (1) sometimes log rotated siblings are not compressed so they won't end in `.gz`. I should mention that as a possibility in the question. Including `foo.[0-9]*` opens it up to match `foo.0a` which would be a bug in my code. Also (2) the original would match `foo.0a.gz` which is admittedly an unlikely file name in a log directory. Listing possibilities with `[[:digit:]]` handles that and may be worth the ugliness in my case but then I'm handling one and two digit numbers, not n digits. (Log rotation aside, I'd still wonder if there's a way to handle 1 to n digits with glob.)

Comment: To answer your question, there is no glob pattern to match a series of digits.      I would use a glob to find a good set of candidates and, if further winnowing were needed, pass that set through a regex.  That's would be efficient and flexible.

Comment: If you incorporate this is in your answer, I can accept it

Comment: Done.  I think the answer now incorporates our in-comment discussion.

Answer (score -2):

Because `[:digit:]` means `[0-9]`, if you want to match one or more digits, use the "one or more" operator in conjunction.

Result:
`+([0-9])`

Need to test glob patterns? DigitOceans has a nice tool published here.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob

Good luck!

Comment: This is not specified by POSIX as requested by OP.

Comment: For me, I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

Comment: There is no "one or more" operator for globs

Comment: This requires  

`shopt -s extglob`  I believe (aka extended globbing)

Comment: @Vinny It does, but it's still non-POSIX.